# SSRS SharePoint Integrated Mode: The status code returned from the server was: 12019

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I am running SSRS in SharePoint Integrated Mode and just recently started receiving the following error message when viewing a long-running report:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 12019

This report typically runs in 2 - 5 minutes.

The ULS Logs report the following:

> - RunningJobContext.IsClientConnected; found orphaned request tuwr4urvgpx4ad45s5lmaz55
> - DataPrefetch abort handler called for Report with ID=. Aborting data sources
> - Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: Report processing has been canceled by the user. ;
> - Data set 'DataSetName': Report processing has been aborted.

The reports will load fine within SQL Server Data Tools 2012.

Version Info: SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (Reporting Services)

**Additional Info**

I found a workaround that will allow the report to run if I change the URL to https://. It almost appears that there is a different timeout for SSL vs. Non-SSL report requests.

Comment: Hi Robert, if you could add some metrics about how long the report runs for, how big it is etc. That might be useful. It certainly looks like the browser has timed out and left the request running as an 'orphan'. I just did a google on 'ssrs client timeout' and there's some useful looking stuff there, including stackoverflow. Also what version are you running?

Comment: hi did you solved your issue i also facing same issue when browse report from internet we have firwall

Comment: @adilahmed No I never solved the issue, we had to force a redirect on the WFE to https:// and avoid http:// altogether.